Elixir/Phoenix Ecto: Updating All Children in a Limitless Nested Recursive Association
I have these tables folders,  and files
Folder
schema "folders" do
  field :name, :string
  field :archived, :boolean

  belongs_to :folder, Folder
  has_many :folders, Folder
  has_many :files, File
end

File
schema "files" do
  field :name, :string
  field :archived, :boolean

  belongs_to :folder, Folder
end

The archived column is used when we soft delete folders and files.
A parent Folder can have unlimited children folders and files.
FolderA
 |-file1
 |-file2
 |-folder_b
    |-file1
    |-folder_c
       |-file1
       |-folder_d
         ...
         # NO_LIMIT

Now, what I need to do is, If I soft-delete FolderA, All it's children folders and files down the line should be also be soft-deleted (updated archived value into true).
How do I accomplish this in Ecto or even in PostgreSQL?

I modified the example from the Ecto docs (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#with_cte/3-recursive-ctes) to suit your needs:
  def soft_delete_tree_for_folder(root_folder) do
    root_id = root_folder.id
    folder_tree_initial_query = where(Folder, [f], f.id == ^root_id)
    folder_tree_recursion_query = join(Folder, :inner, [f], fo in "folders_tree", on: fo.folder_id == f.id)
    folder_tree_query = union_all(folder_tree_initial_query, ^folder_tree_recursion_query)

    Folder
    |> recursive_ctes(true)
    |> with_cte("folders_tree", as: ^folder_tree_query)
    |> join(:left, [f], fo in "folders_tree", on: fo.id == f.folder_id)
    |> group_by([f], f.id)
    |> select([f, fo], f)
    |> Repo.soft_delete_all()
  end

But it does not work :( I am leaving it here anyway because 1. there is no other information and 2. it may save time for others with the same idea.
